# Blackberry Debugging Tool Issues

Tags: blackberry

I'm using the Eclipse plugin for a BB project, and at present, it looks like any changes I make to the code won't result in a new COD file being imported to the simulator.  I found this when I was looking at the stack trace from the debugger console output.  A quick google didn't really turn up any results, and I'm getting the same problem when I create a new project and copy over all the code.  Has anyone else had a similar problem, and if so, do you know how I would resolve this?  Build Code Automatically is checked, but the strange thing about my project is that the project folder color isn't the deep blue that a new project gets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  You have really contributed something here, I think.

Comment: Have you checked Activate for BlackBerry in context menu for project?

Comment: Is it gets compiled? Alt+B and see messages from rapc in Console. Workaround may be to load cod from sim directly (File->Load Java Program...)

Comment: Hi,

Yes, Activate for Blackberry is checked.  I will try the cod direct load.  Thanks!

Comment: Didn't seem to work.  This kind of problem seems a bit ridiculous to me...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any libraries? if you are currently open on a library file and select debug or run, it'll only load the library, and your app wont change.